# Vector not evaluating as empty

Tags: c++, vector

I am a student learning c++. I am having an issue with an assignment that is causing a while loop to never evaluate as empty.

This program reads user input to generate n number of Aircraft objects. The program first inserts these Aircraft objects into a vector named simulation. Then, while this vector is not empty, the program checks if the user defined time of the object matches the current time step of the simulation. If this evaluates as true, the object is then pushed into a priority heap structure and removed from the initial vector.

I believe this error originates from the following code:

```
//collect aircraft data from cin
    vector<Aircraft> simulation;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cin >> time >> id >> status >> priority;
        //create aircraft object
        Aircraft flight = Aircraft(time, id, status, priority);
        simulation.push_back(flight);
    }

    /*Start Simulation*/
    time = 0;
    //while there are still scheduled flights
    while (!simulation.empty()) {
        cout << "Time step " << time << endl;
        cout << "   Entering simulation" << endl;
        //for each flight scheduled in simulation
        for (int i = 0; i < simulation.size(); ++i) {
            //check if there are any flights entering simulation for time step
            if (simulation[i].getTime() == time) {
                simulation[i].printAircraft();
                //Assign flight runway
                //Runway B prioritizes departures
                if (status == "departing" ) {
                    A.push(simulation[i]);
                    simulation.erase(simulation.begin() + i);
                //Runway A prioritizes arrivals
                } else if (status == "arriving") {
                    B.push(simulation[i]);
                    simulation.erase(simulation.begin() + i);
                }
            }
            time++;
        }
        //Print flights leaving simulation
        cout << "   Runway A" << endl;
        if (!A.empty()) {
            A.peek().printAircraft();
            A.pop();
        }
        cout << "   Runway B" << endl;
        if (!B.empty()) {
            A.peek().printAircraft();
            A.pop();
        }
        //increment time
        time++;
    }
```

Here is the full program if it is helpful:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <algorithm>
#include <climits>

using namespace std;

struct Aircraft {
    private:
        int id;
        int priority;
        int time;
        string status;
    public:
        //getter methods
        int getID() {
            return id;
        }
        int getPriority() {
            return priority;
        }
        int getTime() {
            return time;
        }
        string getStatus() {
            return status;
        }

        //Constructors
        Aircraft(){}
        Aircraft(int a, int b, string c, int d) {
            time = a;
            id = b;
            status = c;
            priority = d;
        } 
        ~Aircraft(){}
        //print Aircraft
        void printAircraft() {
            cout << "       " << time << " " << id << " " << status << " " << priority << endl;  
        }

};

struct Runway {
    private:
        vector<Aircraft> planes;

        //return parent of Aircraft at index i
        int PARENT(int i) {
            return (i - 1) / 2;
        }
        //return left child of Aircraft at index i
        int LEFT(int i) {
            return (2*i + 2);
        }
        //return right child of Aircraft at index i
        int RIGHT(int i) {
            return (2*i +2);
        }
        //This function compares Aircraft A & B, 
        //returns true if A > B else false
        bool isPriority(int a, int b) {
            if (a && planes[b].getPriority() < planes[a].getPriority()) {
                return true;
            //else if priorities are the same check time
            } else if (a && planes[b].getPriority() == planes[a].getPriority()) {
                if (planes[b].getTime() < planes[a].getTime()) {
                    return true;
                //else if time and priority are tied, check id
                } else if (planes[b].getTime() == planes[a].getTime()) {
                    if (planes[b].getID() < planes[a].getID()) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
        //Recursive heapify-down
        /*Prioritization*/
        void heapify_down(int i) {
            //get left and right index of aircraft being heapified
            int left = LEFT(i);
            int right = RIGHT(i);

            int smallest = i;
            //compare i with left and right child to find highest priority aircraft
            if (left < size() && isPriority(i, left)) {
                smallest = left;
            }
            if (right < size() && isPriority(i, right)) {
                smallest = right;
            }
            //if highest priority is not = i, that means that we must heapify down
            if (smallest != i) {
                swap(planes[i], planes[smallest]);
                heapify_down(smallest);
            }
        }

        //recursive heapify-up
        /*Priority: Priority, Time, ID*/
        void heapify_up(int i) {
            //if Parent has higher priority than Aircraft at i then heapify up.
            if (isPriority(i, PARENT(i))) {
                swap(planes[i], planes[PARENT(i)]);
                heapify_up(PARENT(i));
            }
        }
    public:
        unsigned int size() {
            return planes.size();
        }
        bool empty() {
            return size() == 0;
        }
        void push(Aircraft a) {
            planes.push_back(a);
            int index = size() - 1;
            heapify_up(index);
        }
        void pop() {
            //check if the runway is empty
            if (!planes.empty()) {
                //replace root with last leaf
                planes[0] = planes.back();
                planes.pop_back();
                //heapify down on root
                heapify_down(0);
            }
        }
        Aircraft peek() {
            if (!planes.empty()) {
                return planes[0];
            }
            return Aircraft();
        }
};

vector<Runway> makeAirport();

int main() {
    //initialize Runways
    Runway A;
    Runway B;
    
    //n = number of aircraft in simulation
    int n = -1;
    //initialize aircraft details
    int time = -1;
    int id = -1;
    string status = "Null";
    int priority = INT_MAX;
    
    //read data from cin
    cin >> n;
    //check if valid number of aircraft was entered by user
    while (n <= 0) {
        cout << "Please enter a valid number of Aircraft..." << endl;
        cin >> n;
    }

    //collect aircraft data from cin
    vector<Aircraft> simulation;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cin >> time >> id >> status >> priority;
        //create aircraft object
        Aircraft flight = Aircraft(time, id, status, priority);
        simulation.push_back(flight);
    }

    /*Start Simulation*/
    time = 0;
    //while there are still scheduled flights
    while (!simulation.empty()) {
        cout << "Time step " << time << endl;
        cout << "   Entering simulation" << endl;
        //for each flight scheduled in simulation
        for (int i = 0; i < simulation.size(); ++i) {
            //check if there are any flights entering simulation for time step
            if (simulation[i].getTime() == time) {
                simulation[i].printAircraft();
                //Assign flight runway
                //Runway B prioritizes departures
                if (status == "departing" ) {
                    A.push(simulation[i]);
                    simulation.erase(simulation.begin() + i);
                //Runway A prioritizes arrivals
                } else if (status == "arriving") {
                    B.push(simulation[i]);
                    simulation.erase(simulation.begin() + i);
                }
            }
            time++;
        }
        //Print flights leaving simulation
        cout << "   Runway A" << endl;
        if (!A.empty()) {
            A.peek().printAircraft();
            A.pop();
        }
        cout << "   Runway B" << endl;
        if (!B.empty()) {
            A.peek().printAircraft();
            A.pop();
        }
        //increment time
        time++;
    }
}
```

I think that I may be misunderstanding the uses of vector::erase(), but am unsure how else to remove the objects from the vector until the vector will eventually be empty.

Comment: The `for` loop inside of the `while` loop is modifying the `simulation` vector while iterating through the vector. That is a recipe for disaster. At the very least, you will get your `i` loop counter out of sync and end up skipping `flight` elements. So, either 1) loop backwards instead of forwards, or 2) don't increment `i` on any iteration where you have `erase()`'d the element located at `i`. You should also update your `while` loop to handle the case where the `for` loop doesn't find any elements to erase, thus leading to an endless loop.

Comment: You have written code that is very hard to get right: Iterating over the contents of a vector, while (possibly) removing those contents. Note that after you've removed an element from `simulation`, the meaning of `i` has changed. It refers to a different element in `simulation`. At a first glance, I would suggest doing two passes. First, put everything into `A` or `B` as appropriate. Second, use something like [erase_if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase2) to remove the elements you just moved.

Comment: Also note that you are also incrementing the time inside the flight check loop - this will mean that not all flights will be checked against all times.

Comment: Thank you for helping out a rookie everyone. I understand what is causing my error now!

Comment: Please post an answer and accept it. This tells the system that the problem is solved, and it helps others who may be encountering the same problem.